# How to get mod rewrite condition "if variable is not" to work

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, oracle-apex

I've installed Oracle Apex and trying to deploy multiple applications with a apache reverse proxy but I cannot get apache to limit a virtual host to one application id.

The virtual host

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias test.example.com
     ServerAlias example.com

     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/ords/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/ords/

     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=101$
     RewriteRule ^/$ f?p=101 [L,P]

    <Location /i>
       ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/i
       ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/i
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

What im trying to do is if the variable p is not 101 I want the proxy to redirect the user /f?p=101 so only the application that I want on that virtual host is accessible and not the other application but I wont work.

If I do /f?p=102 it will show the other application and not redirect me to application 101 again.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Provide me the sample which has to be redirected

Comment: www.example.com/f?p=102::::::: -> www.example.com/f?p=101
www.example.com/f?p=103::::::: -> www.example.com/f?p=101
www.example.com/f?p=104::::::: -> www.example.com/f?p=101

So if the variable p is not 101 I want it to redirect to

Comment: Can you try this. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=101$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  f?p=101 [P]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f?p=100 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f?p=4550 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f?p=4000
 RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/f?p=101:1 [R]
```

So what I am doing is checking if we get the application ID I need to filter out.
After that I just redirect the page to the original page for the application.